# Hide All div's except the one clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have several `div's` and inside each `div` i have `ul's` and `li's`. I have this code working, when user click on some `li` it will show a `div` inside this `li`.

What i need is to let showed the `div` that the user clicked one, and close the others.

Can you help?

Javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('li').each(function() {
    var tis = $(this), state = false, answer = tis.next('#terms, #articlesAnswers').hide().css('height','auto').slideUp();
    tis.click(function() {
        state = !state;
        answer.slideToggle(state);
        tis.toggleClass('active',state);
    });
});
});
```

HTML Code:

```
<ul id="termsArticles">
            <li>Article 1 – Registration, account management and rescission</li>
                <div id="terms">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Access conditions and registration</li>
                            <div id="articlesAnswers">
                                test text!
                            </div>
                        <li>Account Management</li>
                            <div id="articlesAnswers">
                                test text!
                            </div>
                    </ul>
                 </div>

<li>Article 2 – Free services</li>
  <div id="terms">
     <ul>
         <li>publish an ad for a project or event</li>
          <li>apply to an ad</li>
     </ul>
 </div>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7W7y9/)

Comment: it's better to know your HTML structure clearly, words may make things confusing.

Comment: At the very least we'll need the HTML structure. And preferably even a test setup created in a fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Done, could you please check?

Comment: `id` attributes must be unique. Your example code uses the id `articlesAnswers` and `terms` twice.. you should use classes

Comment: you also shouldnt put div elements in a list..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use duplicate ID's on one page. It is incorrect. 
CSS:

```
.active+.terms{height:auto;}
 .articlesAnswers{display:none;}
 .active+.articlesAnswers{display:block;}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#termsArticles li").click(function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass('active')){
        $(this).toggleClass('active')
    } else {
        $(this).parent().find('>li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }
})
```

});

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hzS75/3/) 
For slide effect i created 2 variant of code: with [CSS3](http://jsfiddle.net/SerZb/) and with [JQ](http://jsfiddle.net/7fsv4/).

Comment: Your fiddle does part of what i need. But when you click in the second li inside the first, it closes anyway

Comment: Not working like i need. You have the first LI working nice, but when you click in the first LI: <li>Article 1 – Registration, account management and rescission</li>, all LI's inside should be hide, and only apper <div id="articlesAnswers">test text!</div> after you click in the LI's

Comment: Anon, sorry to be resquesting your help again, but could you please help me finding where to insert "slow" effect when clicking to open, and closing??

Comment: You can do this with CSS3. I changed my code for your request

Comment: I was trying to make something like this effect: http://jsfiddle.net/kunknown/LU7Vy/2/

Answer (score 0):

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7W7y9/7/

I changed your markup though, since it did not make any sense. Don't ever use the same ID twice, take CLASS names instead.

JavaScript now ends up looking like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("li").click(function(e) {
    $(this).parents(".terms").find(".articlesAnswers").hide();
    $(this).children(".articlesAnswers").show();
  });
});
```